# how to call functions from for loop in shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
array_item= (item1 item2)
#function
check_item1 ()
{
 echo "hello from item1"
}
check_item2 ()
{
echo "Hello from item2"
}
#calling functions
for (( i=0; i<${array_item[@]}; i++ ))
{
 check_${array_item[$i]}  # (expecting check_item1 then check_item2 funtion will be called)
}
```

I'm getting error check_: command not found when tring to call check_item1 & check_item2 functions.

Answer (score 5):

```
array_item= (item1 item2)
```

Don't put spaces around the `=` in assignment, it doesn't work. Also this gives me a syntax error about the parenthesis. You could get the `check_: command not found` error if the array elements are unset or empty.

```
for (( i=0; i<${array_item[@]}; i++ ))
```

`${array_item[@]}` expands to all elements of the array, I think you want `${#array_item[@]}` for the number of elements. If the array is empty, this should also give an error, since the other operand to the comparison will be missing.

The `for (( ... )) { cmds...}` construct seems to work in Bash, but the manual only describes the usual `for (( ... )) ; do ... ; done` construct.

Or just use `for x in "${array_item[@]}" ; do ... done` to loop over the values of the array.

If you do need the indices while looping, it might be technically better to loop over `"${!array_item[@]}"`, since the indices don't actually need to be contiguous. That works with associative arrays too.

Answer (score 2):

Just change your for loop :

```
for index in ${array_item[*]}
    do
       check_$index
    done
```

Full script

```
#!/bin/bash

array_item=(item1 item2)

#function
check_item1 ()
{
   echo "hello from item1"
}
check_item2 ()
{
   echo "Hello from item2"
}   

for index in ${array_item[*]}
    do
       check_$index
    done
```

NB: 
     In addition the following funky constructs are available:

```
${array_item[*]}         # All of the items in the array
${!array_item[*]}        # All of the indexes in the array
${#array_item[*]}        # Number of items in the array
${#array_item[0]}        # Length of item zero
```

Comment: It's probably better to use `"${array[@]"`, the difference comes with elements containing spaces. @ vs. * is the same with arrays as with `$@` and `$*`, see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#Special-Parameters